# React Native Typescript : Realation with Java 11 question ..Windows 10

Tags: react-native

I have already installed java 11 ,and I am able to get the jave version from the termina:
[image]

However , when I run on React Native ,I got this error:

[image]

My build.gradle:
[image]

According to the terminal :
[image]

I also attach the line 1  from android/app/build.gradle:

[image]

React Native version :0.68.2
windows 10;

Could anyone help ?!! Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: @Iva Hi Iva,yes, I have setten on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the react native ,and java ,finally solve the problem ..